# os x remove forward slash from filename

Tags: macos, rename

Hi I want to remove all forward slashes from all my files, but do this recursively for every directory in a main directory.

How do I have to modify this script, which works not recursively?

```
for f in "$1"/*; do
dir="$(dirname "$f")"
file="$(basename "$f")"
mv -- "$f" "${dir}/${file//[^_-0-9A-Za-z.]}"
done
```

or better I want to only replace a forward slash in filenames but this for every subfolder in the main folder?

greeting Max

Answer (score 3):

In the BSD layer a forward slash is the path separator. When you encounter a file name with a forward slash the kernel translates the forward slash-`/` to a colon-`:`. So, a file name in the finder application may look like `foo/bar` but in the BSD layer it looks like `foo:bar`.

So, to walk the directory tree use `find` to locate files with `:` in their name. Then, use an inline script with `-execdir` to remove the colons (forward slashes in the finder application) from the file names.

```
find . -type f -name '*:*' -execdir bash -c ' for file
    do
        echo mv -- "${file}" "${file//:}"
    done' sh {} \;
```

This will only list the `mv` command and the operands. If you feel the output will give you your desired results then remove the `echo`.

Comment: Nice solution, which I adjusted by adding the `-depth` option to `find`, else it would rename the "outermost" folders before traversing into them (thus the paths to the "inner" folders and file would no longer be valid). Also I temporarily stored the new filename within the `do` section  as `newFilename=$(echo "${file}" | tr ":" "\\ ") `, such that I could then call `mv -- "${file}" "${newFilename}" ` in order to have properly escaped (!) whitespace instead of the colon character.